# Aggregate In SQL Server Report Builder With Conditions

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Is there anyway to aggregate my report based on conditions?  I have a report that lists all of the details of call center calls.  There's a grouping on the report that separates the data by the representative who took the call.  On the header of each representative grouping, I would like a series of aggregates: the # of calls he / she took (I used a simple count statement for this), the number of resolved calls, and the number of unresolved calls.  There's a column in the details section that lists whether the call was resolved or not.  The following is what I use to calculate total calls:

```
[Count(CALL_ID)]
```

I am looking for something similar to the following pseudo code that will allow me to count the number of calls that were resolved and the number of calls that were unresolved

```
[Count(CALL_ID) WHERE call_status = 'resolved']
```

Is this possible in Report Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - just use the following expressions in the Group Header:

Resolved calls:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!call_status.Value = "resolved", 1, 0))
```

And practically the same for unresolved calls:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!call_status.Value <> "resolved", 1, 0))
```